# git cherry: How to identify equivalent commit by commit message

Tags: git, version-control, git-cherry

In my project there are a `stable` branch and a `dev` branch. Commits are cherry-picked from `dev` branch to `stable` branch.

In order to filter all commits on `dev` that have not been merged to `stable`, `git cherry -v stable dev` looks like a good choice. However it identifies equivalence by diff, which usually changes after resolving merge conflict during `cherry-pick`:

> The equivalence test is based on the diff, after removing whitespace
>   and line numbers. git-cherry therefore detects when commits have been
>   "copied" by means of git-cherry-pick(1), git-am(1) or git-rebase(1).

I was wondering that is there any command that works like `git cherry`, but identifies equivalent commits by commit message?

Comment: If you simply want to clean up the `dev` branch in order to not have changes repeated in multiple commits, you can do `git rebase stable`. Of course, then you have to clean up all conflicts.

Comment: Do you ever force-push `dev`?

Comment: @max630 Nope. `dev` branch is protected by gerrit.

Comment: Commit messages are not reliable.

Comment: @ElpieKay Yeah. Gerrit's `Change-Id` is a far more better solution. Unfortunately in our case many old commits are not marked with correct `Change-Id` so commit messages become our only choice.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no direct way to do this, so I wrote a short script:

```
#!/bin/bash
git cherry -v stable dev | grep + | cut -d ' ' -f 3- > /tmp/unmerged
xargs -a /tmp/unmerged  -I{} git --no-pager log stable --pretty=oneline --grep {} | cut -d ' ' -f 2- > /tmp/cherry-picked
diff /tmp/unmerged /tmp/cherry-picked
```

**Explanation**:

`git cherry -v stable dev | grep + | cut -d ' ' -f 3- > /tmp/unmerged`
writes commit messages of commits that only exist on `dev` branch. These commits include those have been cherry-picked and changed to `stable` branch, and we need to filter out these commits in the next step.

`xargs -a /tmp/unmerged  -I{} git --no-pager log stable --pretty=oneline --grep {} | cut -d ' ' -f 2- > /tmp/cherry-picked` outputs messages of commits from (1) that appears with the same message on `stable`. In other words, `/tmp/cherry-picked` stores all commits that are cherry-picked and changed from `dev` to `stable`.

Finally, `diff /tmp/unmerged /tmp/cherry-picked` gives out all commits on `dev` where no commit with identical commit message is found on `stable`.

Comment: Relying on commit messages is brittle, using `patch-id` is the right way if one wants to match the commits the way `git cherry` does

Answer (score 1):

If commits in `dev` are not rebased, then you could use `git cherry-pick -x`, marking the source explicitly. There is no automatic use of this information, but with some bash fu it is possible to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `patch-id`. This is the mechanism used by `git cherry`.

To find an equivalent of commit `3642151` run:

`git show 3642151 | git patch-id`

You should get a line with two hashes; the first is the patchid (call
it `PATCHID_FROM_ABOVE`)

`git log -p | git patch-id | grep PATCHID_FROM_ABOVE`

This should give you a list of all commits that correspond to that patchid.

Stolen from: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-cherry-to-find-equivalent-commit-IDs-td3440883.html

Comment: The diff of a commit may change after resolving conflicts during `cherry-pick`, and that's why `git cherry` or `git patch-id` does not work in this case.

Comment: Why are you asking "I was wondering that is there any command that works like git cherry"?